# Understanding Meyers-Serrin theorem: about the use of mollifiers.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

I have read through the Meyers-Serrin theorem, and would like to understand why a simpler argument would not work. The theorem states that $C^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is dense in $W^{k,p}(\Omega), 1 \le p < +\infty.$

In the following we assume $k = 1$ and $\rho_{\epsilon} $a sequence of mollifiers.

For $u \in W^{1,p}(\Omega),$ we consider $u, \nabla u \in L^p(\mathbb{R}^n),$ through natural extension through zero. Then we know:

- $u*\rho_{\epsilon} \rightarrow u$
- $\nabla u*\rho_{\epsilon} \rightarrow \nabla u$

where both convergences are in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$. From here we find:

- $u*\rho_{\epsilon} |_{\Omega} \rightarrow u|_{\Omega} $
- $\nabla u*\rho_{\epsilon}|_{\Omega}  \rightarrow \nabla u|_{\Omega} $

here both convergences are in $L^p(\Omega).$ So we have almoast proven convergence in $W^{1,p}(\Omega),$ as soon as we know that $\nabla u*\rho_{\epsilon}|_{\Omega} = \nabla (u*\rho_{\epsilon}|_{\Omega})$ as a distribution on $\Omega.$ Is this last statement false? Because it seems true to me, and it should follow from the general results on derivatives of a convolution with a distribution.

Thanks for the help in making my trhoughts clearer! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first step already fails: The extension by zero will in general not produce a function $u$ that has a weak derivative on $\mathbb R^n$. Think of $u\equiv 1$ on $\Omega$.

This implies that one cannot mollify in a way which uses values of $u$ outside of $\Omega$. Hence, the proof uses translations to stay away from the boundary of $\Omega$.

Comment: Note to OP: you might know about distributional derivatives and hope that those fix the problem of non existing derivatives of your approach. Indeed, this justifies your definitions but then the mollified sequence does not converge in $ W^{1,p} $. (It does on each compactly contained subset of \Omega but that is clearly not enough)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Now I see that (with my unconvinient notation) $(\nabla u) * \rho_{\epsilon}$ is a gradient only if I restrict myself to sets compactly contained in $\Omega.$